# I am not able to access the database from external sd card in Lenovo Vibe P1m & in Redmi

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sdcard

I am not able to access the database from external sd card in Lenovo Vibe P1m and Redmi. But other mobiles like Moto e2, Samsung S3 I am able to access the database from sd card.

Please check below error log

```
04-18 18:53:04.309 7689-7689/com.deltalearn E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/storage/sdcard1/deltalearn/deltalearn.db'.
                                                          android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:836)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:821)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:729)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:722)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.database.DatabaseHandler.<init>(DatabaseHandler.java:87)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.activities.SplashActivity.launchRespectiveActivity(SplashActivity.java:292)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.activities.SplashActivity.access$300(SplashActivity.java:46)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.activities.SplashActivity$9.run(SplashActivity.java:262)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
04-18 18:53:04.310 7689-7689/com.deltalearn D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-18 18:53:04.311 7689-7689/com.deltalearn E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.deltalearn, PID: 7689
                                                          android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0): Could not open the database in read/write mode.
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:836)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:821)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:714)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:729)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:722)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.database.DatabaseHandler.<init>(DatabaseHandler.java:87)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.activities.SplashActivity.launchRespectiveActivity(SplashActivity.java:292)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.activities.SplashActivity.access$300(SplashActivity.java:46)
                                                              at com.deltalearn.activities.SplashActivity$9.run(SplashActivity.java:262)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5651)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Below code I am using to access database from sd card.

SplashActivity:

```
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

DatabaseHandler:

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, AndroidUtils.getExternalStoragePath()
            + File.separator + Constants.DATABASE_FOLDER_NAME
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d("DatabaseHandler::","public DatabaseHandler(Context context)");

    File dbFile=new File(AndroidUtils.getExternalStoragePath()
            + File.separator + Constants.DATABASE_FOLDER_NAME
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME);

    SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);

    Log.d("DatabaseHandler::", "path: route:" + AndroidUtils.getExternalStoragePath()
            + File.separator + Constants.DATABASE_FOLDER_NAME
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

AndroidUtils:

```
public static String getExternalStoragePath() {
    String removableStoragePath = "";
    //working in Moto, but not working in Samsung S3
    File fileList[] = new File("/storage/").listFiles();
    for (File file : fileList) {
        if (!file.getAbsolutePath().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) && file.isDirectory() && file.canRead()) {
            removableStoragePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }
    Log.d("AndroidUtils:: ", "getExternalStoragePath: removableStoragePath:" + removableStoragePath);
    if (removableStoragePath.contains("emulated")) {
        //working in Samsung s3, but not working in Moto
        String path = "";
        File file = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (fr != null) {
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                String s = br.readLine();
                while (s != null) {
                    if (s.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                        String[] tokens = s.split("\\s");
                        path = tokens[2]; //mount_point
                        if (!Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().equals(path)) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    s = br.readLine();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fr != null) {
                    fr.close();
                }
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.d("AndroidUtils::", "getExternalStoragePath: path:" + path);
        return path;
    } else {
        //working in Moto, but not working in Samsung s3
        return removableStoragePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help will be grateful...